# What set would this belong to? Looks like a Star Wars ship, dark red, tan, grey

Tags: set-identification

Would this be a Star Wars vehicle?
[image: Looks like a Star Wars ship, dark red, tan, grey]

Answer (score 5):

[75186-1 The Arrowhead](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=75186-1) based on Light Bluish Gray Tile, Modified 4 x 4 with Studs on Edge and Dark Bluish Gray Panel 1 x 3 x 1; there are only 4 sets that have both, and only one looks anything like this.

[image: 75186]